# automatically add centesimal point on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quantity field that I want to have initial value as 0.00 and as you type you would be replacing the natural numbers, for example, inserting 10 would result 10.00, and inserting 10.5 or 10,5 would result 10.50.

Any ideas?

example code:

```
 Product Code:<input size=10 /><br />
 Amount Needed:<input size=10 placeholder="0.00"/>&nbsp;Unity:<select>
                              <option value="gr">gr</option>
                              <option value="kg">kg</option>
                              <option value="ml">ml</option>
                              <option value="li">li</option>
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
$('#in').change(function() {
  $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in">
```